# Realizing arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, select-by-attribute, python-addin, multithreading

I am curious as to how `arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")` works. I used to execute highlight in the sub thread, but didn't work.

Does it only work in the main thread (including `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management)`?

```
import threading
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class ButtonClass1(object):
"""Implementation for power_line_planning_addin_addin.button (Button)"""

def __init__(self):
    self.enabled = True
    self.checked = False

def onClick(self):
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

    def selected(mxd):
        sql_statement = "[PLANNING_POWER_LINE_ID] = \'%s\'" % ("route_1")
        layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
        for lyr in layers:
            if lyr.name.encode("utf-8") == "plan_project":
                arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", sql_statement)
                arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
                arcpy.RefreshTOC()

    th1 = threading.Thread(target=selected, args=(mxd,))
    th1.start()
    # th1.join()
```

Comment: ArcGIS for desktop is a single thread application, a child thread can't access the map document. Note the current map document only works in ArcMap not in ArcCatalog or command window.

Comment: @MichaelStimson does it have a method to call a function repeatedly(infinitely call) in the python add-in?I can't use infinite loop in the main thread of python add-in code.

Comment: If you do you will lock up ArcMap, try responding to an event instead https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000018000000